# After installing <Error>: entitlement 'application-identifier' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild, provisioning-profile, code-signing-entitlements

I have an `ipa` file which I have build using `xcodebuild` (cmd tools), and successfully **install** on and can see it on my iPad. When I launch it, it just sits with a blank screen and I can see in the console(Xcode)

> : entitlement 'application-identifier' has value not permitted
>   by a provisioning profile)

I have verified using **codesign tools** and all the values are correct on the `ipa` file,

I am using a single target to create multiple apps from different settings and assets.

I resign my app at `xcrun` as I have to copy the assets after the build process. to my understanding while working on this project if I had wrong values, provisioning profile or certificate combination I shouldn't have gotten an `.ipa` that would even get installed on the device.

What looks to be that the `.ipa`  associate a different provisioning profile on the device than what it was build with.

I am a ruby developer so **xCode** and **iOs** development is new to me, any help would be appreciated

```
Jul 30 16:21:36 Mannies-Dev-iPad amfid[996] <Error>: Jul 30 16:21:36  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf CriticalExtensions IssuerCommonName]


Jul 30 16:21:37 Mannies-Dev-iPad amfid[996] <Error>: entitlement 'application-identifier' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile

Jul 30 16:21:37 Mannies-Dev-iPad amfid[996] <Error>: entitlement 'application-identifier' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile

Jul 30 16:21:37 Mannies-Dev-iPad amfid[996] <Error>: entitlement 'application-identifier' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile



 Jul 30 16:21:37 Mannies-Dev-iPad xxx[995] <Error>: objc[995]: Class WebView is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit and /var/mobile/Applications/55025FD7-6F95-4D1B-A98F-766D2638C0BD/xxx.app/xxx. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.


 Jul 30 16:21:38 Mannies-Dev-iPad kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[995] Builtin profile: container (sandbox)



 Jul 30 16:21:38 Mannies-Dev-iPad kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[995] Container: /private/var/mobile/Applications/55025FD7-6F95-4D1B-A98F-766D2638C0BD (sandbox)


 Jul 30 16:21:39 Mannies-Dev-iPad itunesstored[71] <Error>: libMobileGestalt copySystemVersionDictionaryValue: Could not lookup ReleaseType from system version dictionary



Jul 30 16:21:39 Mannies-Dev-iPad itunesstored[71] <Error>: libMobileGestalt copySystemVersionDictionaryValue: Could not lookup ReleaseType from system version dictionary

Jul 30 16:21:40 Mannies-Dev-iPad itunesstored[71] <Error>: libMobileGestalt copySystemVersionDictionaryValue: Could not lookup ReleaseType from system version dictionary



 Jul 30 16:21:41 Mannies-Dev-iPad profiled[981] <Notice>: (Note ) profiled: Idled.



 Jul 30 16:21:41 Mannies-Dev-iPad profiled[981] <Notice>: (Note ) profiled: Service stopping.
```

Comment: Refer: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2242/_index.html

Comment: my entitlement file has all the required values and the app id in it matches the provisioning profile i use, as a test i have tried building with a malformed bundle id and the build process fails indicating the app-id doesn't matches the bundle id